# avoid removing underscores and numbers

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm trying to eliminate all lowercase characters, but VBScript is removing all underscores, lower case letters, and numbers. How can I make it so that it only takes out the lower case and doesn't eliminate my other characters?

```
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "[^A-Z ]"
    .Global = True
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C25")
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then _
            cell.Value = Application.Trim(.Replace(cell.Value, ""))
    Next cell
End With​
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lowercase letter regex is `[a-z]`.

Your regex - `[^A-Z ]` - matches any character that is not an uppercase letter and a space, thus it matches a lot more than lowercase letters.

Since you are removing the letters, you'd better add `+` quantifier after `[a-z]` to match 1 or more occurrences:

```
.Pattern = "[a-z]+"
```

Comment: You'd have to have pretty substantial amounts of consecutive lowercase characters for the quantifier to make a difference, though. Under normal circumstances I'd expect the difference to be a couple milliseconds at most.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Sure, the performance gain is not that tangible, just it should be "easier" for the regex engine since it won't have to stop and resume at each character in a sequence.

Comment: appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

```
.Pattern = "[a-z]+"
```

should do what you're after, this should match all lowercase letters greedily, alternatively if you want to go the other way and ensure that all that's being captured is digits and _ you could do:

```
.Pattern = "[0-9_A-Z]+"
```

Which would match 0-9, A-Z, and _ and nothing else

Comment: Sorry about that, I whipped up the regex outside of an IDE (since I don't have VS installed at work) and didn't realize I left out the quotes